# Converting Empty EditText to Integer Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, null

I have an EditText which will take a number from the user and save it as **sharedPreferences**. I have two Buttons to load and save and a TextView to display a saved data. Everything works fine but if the user enters nothing and saves, the app crashes. Here's the Kotlin code,

```
override fun onClick(p0: View?) {

    val sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("key", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    when(p0!!.id){


        //saves user data
         R.id.btn_save->{          
            
            val userAge = Integer.parseInt(ageInput.text.toString()) //the problem is here
            
            val editor=sharedPreferences.edit()
            editor.putInt("age",userAge)
            editor.apply()

        }

        //loads or displays user data
        R.id.btn_load->{

            val age=sharedPreferences.getInt("age",0)
            showTv.text="Age: $age"

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `toIntOrNull()` instead. Instead of throwing an exception on invalid input, it returns null. Then you can use the Elvis operator to provide the default to use when it's null.

```
val userAge = ageInput.text.toString().toIntOrNull() ?: 0
```

You should avoid the Java primitive wrapper classes like Integer when using Kotlin.

Comment: Thanks it helped. Just had to do a little bit of edit,             
`val userAge=ageInput.text.toString().toIntOrNull() ?: 0`

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry. This is because `TextView.text` returns a CharSequence rather than a String.